# xmlvm - import errors compat libs in xcode

Tags: android, objective-c, xcode

Does anyone know where the android compat libary is
located in xmlvm so I could copy it by myself to the project folder because this is
what I guess is missing, also would be provided by target=android-on-iphone but as mentioned below this target isn't available in the current build.

I had absolutely no problem installing xmlvm and getting in touch with the
demo/samples also all the demos worked perfectly for me.

But now im stuck at the last 4 errors in xcode, i migrated my android project via `--
skeleton=android:migrate` then cross-compiled it via `--target=iphone` and opened
up the project in Xcode. after few project setup changes the errors went down from
72 to 4 errors ;)

however the errors are importing file not found errors of compat libs, so this
should somehow get to be solved i think...

is it because `--target=android-on-iphon`e wasnt used by me because this option
will copy the android compat libary to the project folder.. well i tried to use this
target mentioned in 2 documentations of xmlvm but in the actual build of xmlvm
this target however does not exist..

How to solve these errors?

Screenshots:

http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/8957/bildschirmfoto20120620u.png

http://imageshack.us/f/138/bildschirmfoto20120620u.png/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it looks like you are using part of the Android API which is not yet implemented.
Unfortunately it seems that you either need to rewrite your application or implement the API yourself.